# Is it possible to copy build files to multiple drop folders on TFS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have two web servers that I am testing with some MVC applications. When I create a build definition in Visual Studio I would like to utilize two drop folders (one on each server) but this doesn't seem possible. I know there are a lot of ways around this by manually copying the files, setting up a data replication or creating multiple build definitions but I am looking for the simplest way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a post-build script that will copy the files to the second web server.

Comment: I did this but ran into a little trouble. I know my script works from running it outside Visual Studio but it doesn't copy all the files when it runs automatically through the post-build script path in the build definition. This is because the build is waiting to drop the files until the script is run but the script actually needs to run after these files are in the drop folder. With the current setup I only end up copying one log file over. Any ideas on how to change this?

Comment: For this issue you can use the build template provided [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/10/10/trigger-release-from-build-with-release-management-for-visual-studio-2013-update-3.aspx) that has Post-Drop script parameters or you can implement a while in your post-build script:
`
 while(-not(Test-Path "$($webPackagePath)\Web.zip"))
 {
  Start-Sleep -s 5   
  Write-Verbose "Waiting for build to finish..." -Verbose
 }
`

Answer (score 0):

The result of a build is always one drop folder, however you will get a subfolder for each web application(look in /_PublishedWebApplications/MyWeb/). As either a post build PowerShell, or as a release management activity you can have both of those web applications deployed to one or more servers.

In the default build template there are place to call PowerShell. You should use the post-test location to call a script that deploys your apps.

If you have a progression of environments, like dev->qa->prod, then you can use the release management tool to create a pipeline for each or both of your applications.